# Laptop-TV sync problems in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: hdmi

I am using Dell Inspiron N4010 Laptop. Recently I have upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04. When I connect my laptop to my Sony Bravia Television through HDMI cable I can see my desktop wallpaper both in Laptop and TV. But After that whatever I do (Say Playing a video file), I can see the video playing in my laptop but not in the TV monitor.But I am getting the audio. When I was using Ubuntu 12.04 there was no problem.In other partition I am using Windows 7 and everything is working fine Windows 7. Please suggest me what to do.

Answer (score 6):

Open "System Settings" and select "Displays".

"mirror displays" will mirror the laptop display on the external device. This will show the same on both screens but the resolution may be limited.

---

Based on your description, it sounds like you have it set to display as an extended desktop.

Extended desktop settings:

Set "launcher placement" to show on all displays or only the primary display.

"Scale all window contents to match" can be set statically to either desktop individually or set to favor the "Display with largest . . ." or " . . . smallest controls".

Pretty much the same so far but here's where there's been some changes.

The primary desktop is the monitor to the left as seen below (Built in Display):
[image]

To change this, you can click and drag the external monitor to the left of the "Built in Display" as seen here. When you click "Apply" the primary monitor and the active window will change to the external monitor.

[image]

In 12.04, videos and full screen applications such as web browsers would only show full screen on the primary monitor, however, this has changed. In 14.04, videos and web-browsers set to full screen will display full screen on the same monitor as the application. Drag the application to the monitor you wish to display the full screen image and then click full screen or press <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Comment: Is there any short cut keys to do this, because i have my laptop lcd damage and nothing is displaying. the external lcd displays the desktop bu t not having acceess to any controls.